# Delete coredata objects with Custom migration

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to delete objects form coredata with coredata custom migration. I tried it inside following methods. It always failed with error.

- `performCustomValidationForEntityMapping`
- `- (BOOL)endEntityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error`
- `- (BOOL)beginEntityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error`

**Error :**

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The file couldn’t be saved because you don’t have permission." UserInfo={NSPersistentStoreOptions={
  NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption = 1;
}, reason=Unable to write to file opened Read Only.,
```

Comment: That error is not really about migration. It suggests you have a bad file URL somewhere.

Comment: I feel, it is related to readonly managedObjectContext during mapping. I make it work by changing `manager.destinationContext` from manager.sourceContext`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this issue, from the coredatabase `save` operation error, it says files are readonly, which forced me to think for about it and earlier I was deleteing coredatabase objects using `manager.sourceContext`. I feel, coredata intently keep this as readonly during mapping, I decided to delete the objects using `manager.destinationContext` and it works perfectly. Guys, feel free to suggest your inputs, for me it works fine.